# Don't prompt to save login information, but use the already saved logins

Tags: firefox

Using Firefox preferences, you can disable the "Save Password?" prompt by unchecking the `Ask to save logins and passwords for websites` option.

I think this disables Firefox's password manager entirely, and trying to use already saved credentials doesn't work.

Is there any way I could disable the prompt (I've already saved the passwords of the sites where I wanted to save the passwords. The prompt is more annoying than useful to me) but still use Firefox's password manager for the already saved logins?